# Windows Azure Mobile Services first connection in Android

Tags: android, azure, azure-mobile-services, connection-timeout

my application based windows azure mobil services. Application connecting time is well normally but when login to application first time azure mobile services connection is very slow like 10 second, after connection speed is normally. how can i solve this problem?

my codes;

```
private MobileServiceClient mClient;

private MobileServiceTable<products> mProductsTable;


mClient = new MobileServiceClient(
                          "https://example.azure-mobile.net/",
                          "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
                          this).withFilter(new ProgressFilter());;

mProductsTable = mClient.getTable(products.class); 

mProductsTable.where()
             .execute(new TableQueryCallback<products>() {
                   public void onCompleted(List<products> result, 
                                           int count, 
                                           Exception exception,
                                           ServiceFilterResponse response) {
           if (exception == null) {
}  else{
               Toast.makeText(Product.this, "Ops!!! Error.", 1000).show();
           }}
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

If your mobile service is in the free tier, then when it's not being accessed it may get unloaded from memory and stored in disk. At that point, when a request arrives at the service, it first needs to be "rehydrated" into a running process to serve the request. This takes usually 10-15 seconds, which is likely the delay you're seeing. After that, once the service is running, subsequent requests will be responded a lot quicker (since the mobile service process is up and running).

Notice that if you scale your service to one of the paid tiers (basic or standard) this won't happen anymore: the service will be up and running the whole time, with the exception of times when you make changes to your service (redeployments, updating scripts, changing app settings, etc.), at which time the service instance may be recycled as well.